# What can I do to block changing the value attribute from input radio?

Tags: html, forms

Using inspect element someone can simply change the value and unintended data will flow into the database
How can I block that?

eg.

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" name="eg">
```

edited with inspect element to:

```html
<input type="radio" value="sdsadsadsa" name="eg">
```

Comment: By checking at the receiving end that the data recieved is of the correct type and correct value. Try using the concept of whitelisting data.

Comment: There are many ways of editing and sending any type of data to a form receiving point; you can not "block" this as such, but more, you can only *accept* expected values so you need to do this at your receiving end, which depends on which language you are using receiving your form data

Comment: You're starting to realise why zero trust models are becoming popular! Never trust input from untrustable sources - and even for trusted ones, you should still validate what is supplied. Even if you were able to stop someone modifying the element attribute, they could still craft an evil HTTP request by hand. Validate on the server side - and validate it again - and make sure it's escaped before storing in the DB.

Comment: Always validate the inputs you receive before sending them to the backend and yes on the backend you do the same.

Comment: Thats why you have validate your form data from backend and frontend, in this example your backend app should not accept this field if its not numeric value and is integer, and if it have a range it should not go out of this field range bounds, this is an example and this kind of rule should be applied on other fields types, database models in various frameworks usually also have capability to validate data coming from API requests.